# How to update value of dictionary in one go for all items in dictionary?

Tags: asp.net, dictionary, iteration

Is there any way to update the value object of dictionary in one go without performing the iteration for all the items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to update all items "at once".

If you want to update all of the items in a `Dictionary`, you need to go through all of them.

If you want the operation to be atomic, you need to enclose it in a `lock` or another synchronization mechanism.

Comment: There would be a way if all values are referencing the same ([reference-type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx)) object.

Comment: What would the point of this question be(i assume that all DictionaryEntries should get the same value) ? ;-)
Therefore i added this only as comment.

Comment: @Tim it's my requirement as I am using this dictionary for a process and in that process all the dictionary values are changed but when the process finished I record the value in DB and then all the values should be set to a default so the next batch of the process can start ...

Comment: @dvlpr: Then you have to implement your own Dictionary Type, that can have a Default-Value as property and you must overwrite all necessary methods. If the default-value is `!= null` all getter that would normally return the value must return the default-value.